# Do small wordings like "no manufacturing drugs" matter if a technicality is found? e.g. growing pot isn't a drug

Tags: contract-law

In contract law is small wordings important in the sense of getting out on technicalities important? For example a lease for a rental property may state "the premises may not be used for manufacturing drugs or other controlled substances". Could someone growing marijuana successfully argue that marijuana may be a drug but they weren't manufacturing it; they were growing it? I red in the question about gag orders and warrant canaries, these sorts of tricks don't really work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Growing marijuana is very often legally classed as "manufacture of a controlled substance." In criminal law, "manufacture" tends to be explicitly defined to include cultivation, but this is in fact a reasonably common use of the term (it doesn't *have* to mean producing with machinery). And so it's extremely unlikely that anyone will be convinced that you even *might* have thought the agreement didn't cover growing marijuana. The intent of the parties is fairly clear there.

Answer (score 0):

In general a contract is a shared understanding of an agreement between the parties - the words on paper are only necessary as evidence of what that understanding is.

If someone can convince a court that any word made a difference to how you understood the contract, then that could affect the ruling.

In this example I agree with cpast that a court would be unlikely to believe that 'manufacturing' was understood in a way that excludes growing plants.

Comment: re:"In general a contract is a shared understanding of an agreement between the parties - the words on paper are only necessary as evidence of what that understanding is." what if the only communication they had was on paper? For example, could a defendant argue "we never actually discussed anything, I just signed the contract which clearly said don't *grow* drugs"?

Comment: I don't quite see what you're asking. If the only communication was a written contract then the court would have to look at the words of the contract and work out how the parties understood them.